# Rounded sides, but sharp cornered rectangle in Inkwell customborder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to achieve a cool shape in Inkwell custom border and it's seems impossible. I want to achieve an overlay custom border which has the horizontal sides curved outside and sharp corners. I have attached an image, this is the fashion I want to achieve. Currently I have used a rounded rectangle border, but this only rounds the corners of the border but I want to make the sides curvy and the corners to be sharp.

[Click here for the image of the Border fashion I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2mpQ.jpg)

```
      {BuildContext context,
      IconData icon,
      int index,
      Function onTapped,
      IconData faicon}) {
    var provider = Provider.of<AppData>(context);
    return Material(
      child: InkWell(
          customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            provider.currentIndex = index;
            if (provider.currentIndex == 0) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, FadeRoute(page: HomeScreen()), (route) => false);
            } else if (provider.currentIndex == 1) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, FadeRoute(page: SearchScreen()), (route) => false);
            } else if (provider.currentIndex == 2) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
                  FadeRoute(page: AppointmentsScreen()), (route) => false);
            } else if (provider.currentIndex == 3) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, FadeRoute(page: ProfileScreen()), (route) => false);
            }
          });
        },
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          height: 8.0.h,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
          child: (faicon != null)
              ? Center(
                  child: FaIcon(
                    faicon,
                    size: 19.0.sp,
                    color: index == provider.currentIndex
                        ? kAppColorLimeGreen
                        : Colors.black54,
                  ),
                )
              : Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    size: 22.0.sp,
                    color: index == provider.currentIndex
                        ? kAppColorLimeGreen
                        : Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `child: Center(
child: InkWell(
/* https://gist.github.com/pskink/41bbb30e1d06de078bf59a10341ac29c */
customBorder: ShapeBuilder(myShape),
onTap: () {},
child: SizedBox.expand(),
),
),

Path myShape(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) {
rect = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32).deflateRect(rect);
return Path()
..lineTo(rect.topRight.dx, rect.topRight.dy)
..arcToPoint(rect.bottomRight, radius: Radius.circular(rect.width / 2 + 32))
..lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy)
..arcToPoint(rect.topLeft, radius: Radius.circular(rect.width / 2 + 32));
}`

Comment: It's actually a circle that its top and bottom is hidden by rectangle parent

Answer (score 1):

Use **ClipRect** widget to clip a circle Container widget. Here's the code:

```
               InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: ClipRect(
                      child: Align(
                        heightFactor: 0.7,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.shopping_bag_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Cart",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```